# Given the lenght of the twine, how one could determine the sizes of letters in a word made of this twine?

Tags: algorithms, puzzle, dimensional-analysis

I have a twine 5 meters long. I would like to arrange the word "MARYSIA" from that tape, keeping all letters the same size, it is ok to cut the twine. I want to choose well known Arial typeface, so I could easily determine the ratios of the letters. How I could determine the size of the letters? First, it could be height, then all other dimensions from the ratios. It could also be an iterative way.

When I am thinking about this problem, I would start with one letter. I would the twine on the floor and would form the letter M (it would be big, 5 meters is a lot of the twine). Then I could shrink the first letter "M" and take the spare twine to form "A", and so on. Finally, I would get all letters in the same size.

Please, how to proceed with such a task only theoretically? Just using pencil and paper (and finally a computer, I can do some calculations using JavaScript)

Comment: What is a twine?

Comment: A thread, a string or a cord made of cotton or something soft

Comment: Do you want the string in the middle of each stroke, or the outline of each letter? (since it is big, these could look very different). I think since the strokes in Arial are very uniform, so I think a good estimate would be to take a screenshot of MARYSIA written in Arial and check what % of the screenshot is made up of text

Comment: I would like it simple, with no outline, just a string in the middle of each stroke. What will it do for me to do the screenshot you propose? What for is that % necessary?

Comment: @Marecky since the strokes are uniform, the area that a stroke takes up is more or less proportional to how long it is. This fails at the crossings, if you dont want to cut so much

Answer (score 1):

Start from the fact that the length of each string needed for a specific letter scales linearly with its height $h$ and also linearly with its width $w$. Keeping the aspect ration this means
$$
l_i(\gamma h,\gamma w)  = \gamma^2 l_i(h,w)
$$
Doubling the size means you need four times the length. You can think of starting with fixed $h$ and $w$ and adjusting $\gamma$ until
$$
\sum_i l_i = 5m
$$
From this you can calculate $\gamma$
$$
5m = \sum_i l_i(\gamma h,\gamma w) = \gamma^2 \sum_i l_i(h,w)
$$
since you know the initial length $\sum_i l_i(h,w)$. This leads to
$$
\tilde{l}_i = l_i(\gamma h,\gamma w) = \frac{5m}{\sum_i l_i} l_i
$$
where the $l_i$'s are the initial lengths of letter $i$ and the $\tilde{l}_i$'s are the letters you want to use.